# How to properly migrate website to new server without screwing the character set?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I'm trying to migrate an website to a new server. Unfortunately I'm getting some problems with the used characters. For example:

The text "atrás" appears as "atr�s".

Almost all text is in a mysql database with Character Set latin1 and Collation latin1_swedish_ci.

I've compared the databases in both servers and they are identical. I can't see what causing this problem.

I've added AddCharset to the .htaccess without success:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddCharset ISO-8859-1 .html .htm .php
</IfModule>
```

or simply:

```
AddCharset ISO-8859-1 .html .htm .php
```

You can see both sites in:

[the one that works](http://www.lacatoni.pt)

[the one that doesn't work](http://www.lacatoni.com.pt)

Also I might add that I didn't develop the mentioned website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new server is sending a charset=UTF-8 header while your content is encoded in iso-8859-1. 
Check the Content-Type configuration in your virtual host.

Comment: Check your .htaccess file if you have it. If you have access to the server you can check your apache virtual host configuration for the site or the general apache conf file.
You can read about this here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html

Comment: I've tried to change the .htaccess file without success. I've updated the question. Please take a look at it.

Comment: try AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1